# Image to Canvas / HTML5 Conversion

Tags: image, html, canvas, file-conversion

Are there software/services for automated conversion of a typical image format (png, bmp, jpg/gif even) to Canvas / HTML5?

Answer (score 14):

Here is a tool that will generate JavaScript code to draw the image on canvas: http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/img2canvas/

Comment: Thanks for actually answering OP's question.  The other answers on this page are irrelevant.

Comment: This tool does the job, but it's also really inefficient.  It does a fillRect for each pixel and doesn't recognize continuous lines or boxes at all, much less circles or other shapes.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need no conversion, just use the image (either new by url or any one in the DOM) by

```
canvas.drawImage(image, dx, dy)
canvas.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dw, dh)
canvas.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)
```

(taken from [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage)).

See the tutorial on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Drawing_images).

Comment: what if you want to manipulate the pixel data of the image using canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the site listed above, but here is the relevant code:

```
function convertImage(canvas, callback) {
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
callback(image);
}
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Also, I put together a [working jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danholder/RS6TG/1/).

Comment: This converts a canvas to an image, but the question was to convert an image to a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

w3school has the answer:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // draw cloud
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(170, 80);
      context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
      context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
      context.stroke();

      // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) can actually save files to HTML5 Canvas format. Tested for SVG.